# Why I can't use location.reload as callback?

Tags: javascript

I need to pass a callback function to one of my functions. But the `location.reload` callback doesn't work.

[image: error]

How should I solve the problem?

Comment: You can use:
var callback = () => location.reload()

Comment: As mentioned in the duplicate, it should be `const callback = window.location.reload.bind(window.location)`